# Can an Angular Application call Multiple API/Servers?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, http, security

I have an Angular SPA (Single Page Application) that calls the server API. All is workng well, but we have been instructed to change the technology stack of the server. We are considering replacing a subset of the API calls (a small subset at first) with the new technology, on a separate server.

Is there any security limitation that could prevent the Angular application/browser to call a subset of the API on "Server1" and the other subset of the API on "Server2"? I remember Javascript had some limitations, but I don't know if they apply to Angular.

Comment: Basically, it works, but it is unclear what the problem exactly is. Have you tried it and encountered problems?

Comment: @Silvermind We have not yet developed anything on the new application. We'll be probably doing a proof of concept soon. Thank you for your response. That encourages me to go forward.

Comment: If you have a restrictive [Content-Security-Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP), then you will have to update it to include the Server2 domain.

Comment: @sombrerogalaxy Oh... thanks for the warning. Since I would prefer not to deal with a CSP I think I'll use the same scheme://host:port, but a different path "/api2"; the load balancer will route -- behind the scenes -- anything starting with "/api2" to Server2.